# why RAW column can print only 255 characters in console?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have a oracle db table like this

```
create table test_1 (col RAW(255));
```

and inserting to table

```
insert into test_1 (col) values ('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');
```

but when i select, it can show only 255 chars. Initially i thought "05" is stored as 2 bytes. but its not because i am able to add even more chars

```
SQL> select * from test_1;

COL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
050003500201596F7572206F7574676F696E6720616E64204254434C20696E636F6D696E67206361
6C6C207365727669636520686173206265656E2074656D706F726172696C79206261727265642E20
50617920796F75722062696C6C2077697468696E203330206461797320746F2061766F696420626F
746820776179206
```

Above is the result what i get.

Can any one tell me, how to display all the chars? One of my client is complaining that he is able to get only partial data (like select output). but when i checked locally i am able to get correct data in code but only select in console shows wrong data.

OS: SUSE
oracle 11g

pls let me know if any more info is needed.

Regards
Nasir

Comment: You're only getting 255 characters because SQL*Plus is interpreting `raw(255)` as a value that only requires 255 to represent. Not sure why you'd want to display the raw values though? Wouldn't converting this to a VARCHAR2 be better?

Comment: @Ben, its actually content of a message in that first few bytes are not text. Its fine for me to print as chars also. Is there any method for that? Actually i am totally new to oracle. before i just worked on sqlite. Can u tell me if there is any way to get all the bytes (or text) of this column?